# The plane curve of maximum average speed under constant gravitational force

Tags: calculus-of-variations, plane-curves

A **line** gives us the minimum distance from $A$ to $B$. A **cycloid** gives us the minimum traveling time of a point mass from $A$ to $B$ (under constant gravitational acceleration $g$).

What about the curve that maximizes the **average speed** from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Oh, I mean average speed, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's no upper bound for the average speed. The speed is determined by the height; the deeper you go, the higher you can make the average speed.

Comment: What if the endpoints are fixed and one chooses the velocity vector at the initial one?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I don't see why you think that that affects my argument. Which part do you think no longer holds in that case?

Comment: It's not a matter of a conclusion no longer holding. It's a matter of covering all cases. If the same conclusion holds for all cases, why not briefly mention it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: There are all sorts of cases the question didn't ask about. I merely answered the question. I think it's clear enough that the argument is quite fundamental and independent of the details of the boundary conditions.

Comment: Ok. So, what about the minimum value of average speed? Is there any bound?

Comment: @ahmedbilal: No, there isn't. You can go almost to the height at which the speed is zero and move around there with arbitrarily low speed for an arbitrarily long time and distance to make the average speed arbitrarily close to zero (and of course it can never be zero).

Comment: This answer looks fundamentally incomplete to me. As the height grows, so does total distance covered, but what about total travel time? How is the growth relation between those two? Doesn't really look all that obvious to me.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: I'm not sure which of the two questions you're adressing. In the original question, which intended to maximise the average speed, the height doesn't grow; we go to lower and lower heights. For any given curve, insert an additional curve segment at its lowest point, below that point. Then the motion in the previously existing curve segment takes the same time and covers the same distance as before, and additionally the lower curve segment is traversed, with greater speed. Hence the average speed of the augmented curve is greater than that of the previous curve.